# Why does Spring Aspects depend on Spring ORM?

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies

I have a project with a dependency to `org.springframework:spring-aspects` which used to work fine with some Spring 4.x version. Now I've updated to some Spring 5.x version and the application refuses to start with `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceUnit' available`
It turned out this could be resolved by excluding the newly added dependency to `org.springframework:spring-orm`. Is this the expected way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We hit the same thing. It seems it's a bug that's already been fixed in Spring 5.2.4 (released on [Feb 25th, 2020](https://spring.io/blog/2020/02/25/spring-framework-5-2-4-and-5-1-14-available-now)) - see Spring Framework issue [#24491](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24491).

So it seems the right thing to do, until you can pick up this release, is to exclude `spring-orm` as you've done.